# I need to print value from 3rd column when 4th column condition is matched

Tags: linux, awk

```
cat Data.log 

REPLICAT RUNNING RPGUJ3   02:00:12 00:00:06
REPLICAT RUNNING RPGUJ4   00:00:10 00:00:06
REPLICAT RUNNING RPGUJ3_3 01:00:11 00:00:00
REPLICAT RUNNING RPGUJ4_3 00:00:12 00:00:06
```

I want to print those value from column 3rd , which is having time greater than or equal to 1 hr from column 4th only
output be like :

```
RPGUJ3
RPGUJ3_3
```

I tried below to get the output of 3rd and 4th column in single file

```
cat Data.log | awk '{print $3 "     " $4}' >1.out

cat 1.out 

RPGUJ3      02:00:12
RPGUJ4      00:00:10
RPGUJ3_3    01:00:11
RPGUJ4_3    00:00:12
```

but i am unable to to print

```
RPGUJ3
RPGUJ3_3
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your question right, you want to print only the names of the jobs that run longer than one hour. This *might* be a bit more than one-liners with `awk` and `grep` can get you; you might want to consider writing a full script, either in shell or whatever scripting language you're most familiar with.

Comment: @Shadur you may misunderstand awk as this is exactly the kind of job for it. grep and awk are not close to similar in what they can do. `grep` is just for doing `g/re/p`, i.e. Globally matching a Regular Expression and Printing the result, while awk is a full scripting language for manipulating text that can do what grep does but also vastly more. A shell is a tool for manipulating (creating/destroying) files and processes and sequencing calls to other tools. It is not a tool for manipulating text so the only part of this you'd do in shell is to call a tool designed to manipulate text from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the first two digits of $4 are not `00`:

```
awk 'substr ($4, 1, 2) != "00" { print $3; }' Data.log > 1.out
```

`awk` can read its own datafiles -- no need for `cat` and a pipeline.

```
$ cat Data.log
REPLICAT RUNNING RPGUJ3   02:00:12 00:00:06
REPLICAT RUNNING RPGUJ4   00:00:10 00:00:06
REPLICAT RUNNING RPGUJ3_3 01:00:11 00:00:00
REPLICAT RUNNING RPGUJ4_3 00:00:12 00:00:06
$ awk 'substr ($4, 1, 2) != "00" { print $3; }' Data.log > 1.out
$ cat 1.out
RPGUJ3
RPGUJ3_3
$
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your input but no luck.

Comment: cat Data.log
RPGUJ3      02:00:12
RPGUJ4      00:00:10
RPGUJ3_3    01:00:11
RPGUJ4_3    00:00:12
============================                                                               
 awk 'substr ($4, 1, 2) != "00" { print $3; }' Data.log > 1.out                                                   cat 1.out is blanks

Comment: @ANW  Works here. Added my test run to my answer. Perhaps you have hidden characters in your data. Try `cat -vet Data.log` and post that output.

Comment: @ANW Note that you should be running this on your original data, not the 2-column variant of the data.

Comment: Hey Paul .... Thank you so much bro..... I am able to get correct output

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '$4+0{print $3}' Data.log
RPGUJ3
RPGUJ3_3
```

Adding `0` to `$4` tells awk to convert the string, e.g. `02:00:12`, to a number and it does so by first stripping anything after the leading digits, which in this cases is from the first `:`, so the result is just `2`. Then using that resulting number as a condition will be false if the result is `0` , true otherwise, just like in `C` and many other languages:

```
$ awk '{print $4, "->", $4+0, "->", ($4+0 ? "true" : "false")}' Data.log
02:00:12 -> 2 -> true
00:00:10 -> 0 -> false
01:00:11 -> 1 -> true
00:00:12 -> 0 -> false
```